# Powershell -replace <td> with a special character of ">" not working

Tags: html, powershell

I've got a block of code that does `-replace` on a number of `<td>` entries in some HTML output.

The data that is read comes from a .csv, so all values coming in are string type

The entire block of code is as follows:

```
$Report | Select Server, WMI, SVC, UptimeDays | ConvertTo-HTML | ForEach {

$PSitem -replace "<td>Not installed</td>", "<td style='background-
color:Yellow;color=black'>Not installed</td>"`

-replace "<td>Failed</td>", "<td style='background-
color:#FF0000;color=white'>Failed</td>"`

-replace "<td>Installed/Not running</td>", "<td style='background-
color:#FF0000;color=white'>Installed/Not running</td>"`

-replace "<td>WMI timed-out</td>", "<td style='background-
color:#FF0000;color=white'>WMI timed-out</td>"`

-replace "<td>Offline</td>", "<td style='background-
color:#FF0000;color=white'>Offline</td>"`

-replace "<td>Uptime > 7 days</td>", "<td style='background-
color:Yellow;color=black'>Uptime > 7 days</td>"

} | out-String
```

The `-replace` on all  entries, with the expected colored background/text,  but not for the `"<td> Uptime > 7 days</td>"`

...I'm assuming it's because I've got the `">"` in there. I would rather not re-format the input CSV to remove the ">". Is it just a matter of adding an escape "/" character in the right place? How would I do that with the above code?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: ` is the escape char <td>Uptime `> 7 days</td>. But whats the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Thx all, i'm not not getting an error, i'm just not seeing the HTML output in yellow with black text as expected. I will try to use "`" and report back

Comment: I tried adding the "`" but the result was the same, not seeing the output TD in yellow with black text

Comment: i'm using $PSITEM on the for loop, I forgot to include it in the original post, i've added it just now.

The original source is .csv, not html, perhaps that's the reason? CSV import is always string-type right? 

The out-string is working as expected for other <TD> values, for instance

       -replace "<td>Failed</td>", "<td style='background-
      color:#FF0000;color=white'>Failed</td>"`
 
sets the TD with a red background, white text, as expected.

Comment: The problem you have is not in the part you are showing us. Can you post a minimal in- and output that shows the problem? Following works `"<td>Uptime > 7 days</td> <td>Failed</td>" -replace "<td>Uptime > 7 days</td>", "<td style='background-color:Yellow;color=black'>Uptime > 7 days</td>" -replace "<td>Failed</td>", "<td style='background-color:#FF0000;color=white'>Failed</td>"`

Comment: Full code posted to show all the -replace <TD> entries. As i've said, the color coding works fine on all the other entries, it's just the one with the greater than sign in it. I did try changing the input csv to just state "greater than 7 days" and the color-coding worked fine. I'm just keen to not have to re-write all my scripts that tag using "Greater > 7 days" , I've got dozens.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you didn't answer the relevant part of my comment, I'm pretty certain that's it:

Test data:

```
PS D:\t> 1,2,3|select @{n='num';e={$_}},@{n='days';e={'days > 7'}}

num days    
--- ----    
  1 days > 7
  2 days > 7
  3 days > 7
```

Converted to HTML:

```
PS D:\t> 1,2,3|select @{n='num';e={$_}},@{n='days';e={'days > 7'}} | ConvertTo-Html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>num</th><th>days</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>days &gt; 7</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>days &gt; 7</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>days &gt; 7</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

See the `>` has been replaced with the HTML entity code for the greater-than symbol, `&gt;`.

So your replace will have to match `"<td>Uptime &gt; 7 days</td>"`.

Comment: I agree, that's why I asked for in and outputs but OP doesn't read comments ;)

Comment: I will try the most recent post and report back

Comment: Excellent! 

Doing the -replace on "&gt;" Did it! Thanks so much, TessellatingHeckler